# Google Nearby Publish in background for Android

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-nearby

The Google Nearby library allows publishing in the background for iOS (stated [here](https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/ios/pub-sub#background_operation)) using BLE only. What is the reason for not allowing Android to have the same capability, and will it ever be supported?

Comment: I wonder if this is possible if you display a foreground notification. Could easily add controls to allow the user to turn it off.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason mentioned in [documentation](https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/android/pub-sub) why Nearby Messages API should only be used from a foreground (not in background) is due to potential to impact battery life. But this [article](https://medium.com/@elye.project/android-nearby-connections-vs-messages-a2bdf6a59ff3#.wy28u321y) added that security reasons is one factor why Android activities were prevented in background.

**Will it ever be supported?**

You may want to regularly check [Release Notes for Google APIs for Android](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases) to know the latest updates.